# hash tag scroll and get data through URL, how can I make this two work together?

Tags: html

I need hastag link to work together with GET data in the url.

I tried this: `#comment-72?success=1`

But it doesn't work, what would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be this way

?success=1#comment-72

Comment: thanks :) I actually tried this variation before asking here. but I wanted to be sure it is correct way.